# From where is the PATH value in Fedora env gets populated?

Tags: path, fedora-11

I would like to know from where is the PATH value in the **env** of my terminal (Fedora machine) gets populated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It starts in `/etc/profile`. From there, scripts in `/etc/profile.d` can modify it. Then it goes to `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: my PATH is missing /sbin? how can i add that to my default PATH?

Comment: @Sen: by default /sbin isn't on the path of normal users. The stuff in /sbin is meant for the use of root and superusers only. The typical way to gain access to /sbin stuff is to switch to a superuser account. Either `su -` to root or use sudo to access the stuff like so `sudo /sbin/service`.

Comment: Minor comment for readers: this is the same sequence as in all systems that use bash, not just fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Linux machine at the moment, but isn't that stored in the [.bashrc](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/17142.html) of your home folder?